# Execute a JS function every n-time in Angular (Primo)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The function should be run every n-seconds:

```
 app.controller('prmServiceHeaderAfterController',[function () {
    var vm = this;     
    vm.func_name = function func_name(obt-var) {
    var timesRun = 0;
    var checkExistenceOfElement = setInterval(function () {
   // ...
    }
        }, 50);
    };
    vm.func_name();
    }]);
```

It works just with a manual page uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's `setInterval` which accepts a callback function and the interva as argunemts

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //your execution logic at regular intervals
}, intervalInMilliSeconts);
```

Comment: I use it, but in Angular in the Primo system, it does not work.